# Copy image pixel by pixel in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am trying to copy a smaller image into a larger image. I get error while I do that. I do not want to use ROI method because I will use this code for many iterations and each time selecting ROI for the image is not efficient and also the ROI will change everytime.
I do not want to copy the image using `copyTo()` function because my next step will be to check if the image pixel is 0(i.e., black), if so not to copy it.
I can read the value of the pixel but when I try to copy it into another image I get an error. I have looked into all the previous posts and tried to do changes, but none of them work. 
I will attach my code and also the error I get.

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
Mat img1, img2, output;

    img1 = imread("E:/Image2.jpg", 1);
    img2 = imread("E:/Marker2.PNG", 1);

    int startrow, startcol;
    startrow = 20;
    startcol = 20;

    int rows, cols,i,j,r=1,c;
    cv::Size s = img2.size();
    rows = s.height;
    cols = s.width;
for (i = startrow; i <= startrow + rows; i++)
    {
        c = 1;
        for (j = startcol; j <= startcol + cols; j++)
        {
            output.at<uchar>(i, j) = img2.at<uchar>(r, c);
            c++;
        }
        r++;
    }
    imshow("Output", output);
    waitKey(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots but paste the actual error message.

Comment: Also, what kind of debugging have you tried. Did you check at which indices the error occurs? You might be accessing the matrix out of bounds.

Comment: @oarfish Thank you. It is not screenshot. I have use the insert code option and inserted it. I get error when the first pixel is accessed. Just to check if the pixel value could be read I tried to read the pixel value at each position inside the for loop as follows:" int val = img2.at<uchar>(r, c); std::cout<<val;  " For this I got the pixel value at img2(1,1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use complicated pixel-position-arguments. Instead just use subimages from ROIs:

```
cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png");
cv::Mat output = input.clone();
cv::Mat marker = cv::imread("../inputData/marker.png");

// subimage dimensions:
cv::Point startPosition = cv::Point(20,20);
cv::Size size = marker.size();

// ROI:
cv::Rect subImageRect = cv::Rect(startPosition, size);

// limit the roi if roi is bigger than the original image:
cv::Rect fullImageRect = cv::Rect(cv::Point(0,0), input.size());

// intersection of both rois
subImageRect = subImageRect & fullImageRect;
if(subImageRect.width == 0 || subImageRect.height == 0)
{
    std::cout << "marker position isn't within the image dimensions" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// subimage = reference to image part of original image:
cv::Mat outputSubImage = output(subImageRect);
// marker subimage should be the whole marker, but might be reduced.
cv::Mat markerSubImage = marker(cv::Rect(0,0,subImageRect.width, subImageRect.height));

// now just copy the data:
markerSubImage.copyTo(outputSubImage);
// if you don't want to use .copyTo, just use a loop over 0 .. subImage.width/height and copy from same pixel location to same pixel location.
cv::imshow("output", output);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

With this input image:

[image]

and this marker image:

[image]

it generates this output:

[image]

if you are sure that the marker is within the image, you can remove the sanity checks to simplify code:

```
cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png");
cv::Mat output = input.clone();
cv::Mat marker = cv::imread("../inputData/marker.png");

// subimage dimensions:
cv::Point startPosition = cv::Point(20,20);
cv::Size size = marker.size();

// ROI:
cv::Rect subImageRect = cv::Rect(startPosition, size);
// subimage = reference to image part of original image:
cv::Mat outputSubImage = output(subImageRect);

// now just copy the data:
marker.copyTo(outputSubImage);
// if you don't want to use .copyTo, just use a loop over 0 .. subImage.width/height and copy from same pixel location to same pixel location.
```

Comment: thank you so much for the code. In my actual code I need to apply projective transformation on the image. After applying projective transformation the result is like this: http://i.imgur.com/Sac81G8.png .  Next when I copy the the image into my image it is like this: http://i.imgur.com/8RPkPYn.png . So I dont want the black background after the marker is transformed in my image. Hence I need code that can access each pixel and copy it onto the image.

Comment: **Mistake in my code was that I had not copied the initial image into the output image**

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
Mat img1, img2, output;

    img1 = imread("10.jpg", 1);
    img2 = imread("13.jpg", 1);
    output=img1.clone();
    int startrow, startcol;
    startrow = 20;
    startcol = 20;

    int rows, cols,i,j,r=0,c;
    cv::Size s = img2.size();
    rows = s.height;
    cols = s.width;
for (i = startrow; i < startrow + rows; i++)
    {
        c = 0;
        for (j = startcol; j < startcol + cols; j++)
        {
            output.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = img2.at<Vec3b>(r, c);
            c++;
        }
        r++;
    }
    imshow("Output", output);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I did as you told and still get error.

Comment: Next thing: "<= startrow + rows" must be "< startrow + rows" by the same reason.

Comment: And you did not create output matrix.

Comment: set `r` and `c` to `0` too, or see my answer using `cv::Rect` for subimaging

Comment: @Andrey yes you were right. Now I intialized output image as image1. Still I get the same error!!

Comment: I've checked you code, it worked for me. Updated my answer. But really, Micka is right, it's faster to use ROI.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrey Smorodov. Yes Micka's answer is right. But as answered in above comment, in actual code i need to perform projective transformation of my marker image and then not display the extra background got from the projective transformation. For this reason I need to access each pixel.

Comment: I have a question @Andrey Smorodov. Does your code work for this image : http://i.imgur.com/h0sLxGt.png when taken as img2? Can you please check it and let me know.

Comment: Attached the result image.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual error message I'm not sure what exactly is happening.

To me it looks like your problem has to do with allocating output. Try initializing it to a correct size before you start filling in its values.

```
output = Mat::zeros(numRows, numCols, type) // something like this
```

check out the documentation:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-create

Comment: thank you for the reply. The error image got deleted from the question and I cannot edit and upload again. So I will provide you the link: http://i.imgur.com/JiSd02R.png .

Comment: That error probably happened because you're writing to memory that hasnt been allocated. Once you properly allocate memory for "output" it will probably go away. Also watch out for the indices in those for loops

Comment: yes you are right. Now I initialized output= img1.clone(); and also initialized r=0 and c=0. I dont get the error now. But still have some problem reading the second image completely inside for loop. Thank you for the help